# Border-Radius is not creating Rounded Border

Tags: html, css, frontend, border

I have a image picture card. I would like to have rounded border around the whole card. How would I do conduct this? It does not seem to be working property.

Does anyone know the property in CSS or HTML?
The following did not work after doing border-radius property:.
I would like to do it around the card image, instead of the images. We have a 3X3 square gallery, or 4X4 gallery soon, so maybe more difficult to code.

I want the actual images rounded off, not a rounded box

```
border-radius: 25px;
```

```css
.card {
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

.card-header {
    background-color: white;
}

.card-body {
    background-color: white;
}


.cardcheckbox {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    /*vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;*/
    visibility: hidden;
}


input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    visibility: visible;
}

.card:hover .cardcheckbox {
    visibility: visible;
}


.material-icons {
    display: inline-flex;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.card-header .accordion-toggle {
    &.collapsed:after {
        font-family: 'Material Icons';
        content: "\e5cf";
    }

    &:after {
        font-family: 'Material Icons';
        content: "\e5ce";
        float: right;
        color: grey;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="card" style="width: 30.00rem">
   <div aria-multiselectable="true" class="accordian md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist">
      <div class="grid-container" id="gridid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d0852" style="  display: grid;
         grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
         grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
         grid-gap: 0em;
         padding: 0px;
         align-items: stretch;
         position: relative; "><input class="cardcheckbox" id="checkid" type="checkbox"><img id="imgid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d08520" src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; padding: 0px; background-color: white;"><img id="imgid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d08521" src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; padding: 0px; background-color: white;"><img id="imgid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d08522" src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; padding: 0px; background-color: white;"></div>
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne1" role="tab"><a aria-controls="id531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d0852" aria-expanded="true" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-parent="#accordionEx" data-toggle="collapse" href="#id531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d0852">Tree</a></div>
      <div aria-labelledby="headingOne1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" id="id531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d0852" role="tabpanel">
         <div class="card-body">Tree with leaves</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect the images are overlaying the border-radius. Did you try `overflow:hidden` on the container?

Comment: I want the Actual Images Rounded off, not a rounded box

Comment: @Paulie_D it worked! thanks, if you want to write that as answer, I can send points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will implement the

```
overflow:hidden on the container
```

as Paulie D recommended.
Paulie D is free to recopy into his own answer, so I can send points.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Add Padding in .card class, because inner content over-righting the border radius

```
.card {
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Updated Code:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    .card {
        border-color: black;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding: 10px;

    }

    .card-header {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .card-body {
        background-color: white;
    }


    .cardcheckbox {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 5px;
        /*vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;*/
        visibility: hidden;
    }


    input[type=checkbox]:checked {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .card:hover .cardcheckbox {
        visibility: visible;
    }


    .material-icons {
        display: inline-flex;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .card-header .accordion-toggle {
        &.collapsed:after {
            font-family: 'Material Icons';
            content: "\e5cf";
        }

        &:after {
            font-family: 'Material Icons';
            content: "\e5ce";
            float: right;
            color: grey;
        }
    }
</style>
<div class="card" style="width: 30.00rem">
    <div aria-multiselectable="true" class="accordian md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist">
        <div class="grid-container" id="gridid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d0852" style="  display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 0em;
        padding: 0px;
        align-items: stretch;
        position: relative; "><input class="cardcheckbox" id="checkid" type="checkbox"><img
                id="imgid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d08520"
                src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image"
                style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; padding: 0px; background-color: white;"><img
                id="imgid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d08521"
                src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7"
                style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; padding: 0px; background-color: white;"><img
                id="imgid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d08522"
                src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png"
                style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; padding: 0px; background-color: white;"></div>
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne1" role="tab"><a aria-controls="id531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d0852"
                aria-expanded="true" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-parent="#accordionEx"
                data-toggle="collapse" href="#id531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d0852">Tree</a></div>
        <div aria-labelledby="headingOne1" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx"
            id="id531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d0852" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="card-body">Tree with leaves</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the actual images rounded off, not a rounded box

Comment: Update the following if you need images rounded not the card : .card {
        border-color: black;
        /* border-radius: 25px; */
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding: 10px;

    }
    .card img{
        border-radius: 25px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can see like this just make a few changes like this, [Click and see my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHKZ4.jpg)

Create CSS class imgsize and imgfirst like below,  And delete all the styles in HTML file your three images.

```
<img class="imgfirst" id="imgid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d08520" src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image">
<img class="imgsize" id="imgid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d08521" src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7">
<img class="imgsize" id="imgid531937b3b9b54801ab80573cf91d08522" src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png" >

.imgsize{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     padding-top: 12px;
}
.imgfirst{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   padding-top: 12px;
   padding-left: 12px;
 }
```

Then edit "card" and "card-header" class in CSS,

```
.card {
   margin-top: 10px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   border-color: black;
   border-radius: 10px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   width: 100%;
   margin-right: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.card-header {
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: I want the actual images rounded off, not a rounded box

Comment: Then you can update ".imgsize{ border-radius: 10px;} and .imgfirst{ border-radius: 10px;} " .

Comment: Or if you want to special corner : {border-top-right-radius: 10px}